# Combining pyperclip copy-to-clipboard with pyautogui paste?

Tags: python, clipboard, pyautogui, pyperclip

I want to paste some text loaded in from python into a browser field:
Any method to load something into the clipboard, which I can then paste using Ctrl+V. Currently I see pyperclip.paste() only paste the text into the console, instead of where I want it. Pressing Ctrl+V after running `pyperclip.copy('sometext')` does nothing.

```
import pyautogui
import pyperclip

def click():
    try:
        pyautogui.click()
    except:
        pass

pyperclip.copy('sometext')
pyautogui.moveTo(4796, 714)
click()
pyperclip.paste()
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v', interval = 0.15)
```

What am I doing wrong here? An alternative method would be just as welcome as a fix - preferably one that avoids using `pyautogui.typewrite()` as it takes a long time for lots of text

Update: seems to be a problem with `pyperclip.copy('sometext')` not putting or overwriting `'sometext'` into the clipboard. the pyperclip paste function works as it should, and so does the pyautogui Ctrl+V

Comment: `pyperclip.paste()` simply returns the current clipboard contents as a string - it has no effect on any application.  Simulating a Ctrl-V ought to have worked - perhaps you just need a bit more delay after the copy, to let the browser get into a state where it's ready to accept a paste?

Comment: checked that just now, it looks like `pyperclip.copy('sometext')` isnt loading the text into the clipboard. i ran that line individually, then waited a while, then pressed Ctrl+V manually. what got pasted was something I copied a while ago, not 'sometext'

Answer (score 5):

Try using `pyautogui.typewrite` instead:

```
import pyautogui

def click():
    try:
        pyautogui.click()
    except:
        pass

pyautogui.moveTo(4796, 714)
click()
pyautogui.typewrite('sometext')
```

You can find useful information [here](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/).

Answer (score 0):

You could store it as a variable, then use typewrite to input/paste it out.

```
paste_data = pyperclip.paste()
pyautogui.typewrite(paste_data)
```